# Extract a certain number from a text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to kindly ask how to extract certain number(s) from a text? For example I have this text line.

```
Last edited by SarkZKalie on Wed 8 Aug - 2:17; edited 1 time in total
Last edited by SarkZKalie on Wed 8 Aug - 2:17; edited 12 times in total
```

As you can see, this text line existed a date format inside itself but please don't care about it, I just want you to focus the thing "1 time" or "11 times" after it.

The script should return a result looks like .getElementById("lastedit") then insert number we've got in a button html tag.

```
<button id="lastedit" title="Edited NUMBER time(s) in total">NUMBER</button>
```

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example 1 - one line

```js
$("#lastedit").text(
  parseInt("Last edited by SarkZKalie on Wed 8 Aug - 2:17; edited 12 times in total"
    .split(/; edited /)[1]
  )
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="lastedit" title="Edited NUMBER time(s) in total">NUMBER</button>
```

Example 2, sum the number of edits

```js
const list = `Last edited by SarkZKalie on Wed 8 Aug - 2:17; edited 1 time in total
Last edited by SarkZKalie on Wed 8 Aug - 2:17; edited 12 times in total`

$("#lastedit").text(
  list.split(/; edited /) // split on the word before the number
    .slice(1)             // get rid of the first line
    .reduce(( x, v ) => x + parseInt(v),0) // sum the array of numbers
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="lastedit" title="Edited NUMBER time(s) in total">NUMBER</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let str = 'Last edited by SarkZKalie on Wed 8 Aug - 2:17; edited 12 times in total'
console.log(get(str))

var str2 = 'Last edited by SarkZKalie on Wed 8 Aug - 2:17; edited 1 time in total'
console.log(get(str2))

function get(str) {
  const match = str.match(/\d+/g)
  return match[match.length - 1]
}
```

Comment: @mplungjan That's better?

Comment: Also I believe he wants to sum the number of edits. Please see my answer

Comment: Thank you both for your help. These script are great and easy to understand, it will help me learning more here. And yes, I want to sum the number of edits.